# postgres view showing todays orders

Tags: postgresql

Is there a variable built into postgres to represent "today"? I want create a view of a table that only shows data that was entered "today" there is a datetime field that represents the date / time an order was entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table where date("created_date") = current_date();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `CURRENT_DATE`

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE;
```

See [Date/Time Functions](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/functions-datetime.html)